# How to add a dropdown or checkbox to the filter in Material-UI dataGrid/XGrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, xgrid

I am trying to add a checkbox or dropdown to one of the column filter. I have tried using type="boolean" to the columns, it is creating the dropdown but not it not creating the list as I expect. I am expecting the dropdown with two option like "Reachable" and "Unreachable" but it is creating "true" or "false".

Is their any prop name to create the names for the Filter types? I am expecting like this
[image]

or

[image]

But I am getting like this

[image]

My code looks like this

```js
let rows = list.map((obj, index) => {
  return (rows = {
    id: index,
    "Device ID": obj.device_ID,
    Status: obj.device_status,
    "Last Reading": obj.device_time
  });
});

const columns = [
  {
    field: "Device ID",
    flex: 1,
    renderHeader: () => <FormattedMessage id={"device.param.deviceMrid"} />
  },
  {
    field: "Status",
    flex: 1,
    type: "boolean",
    renderHeader: () => <FormattedMessage id={"history.param.deviceStatus"} />
  },
  {
    field: "Last Reading",
    flex: 1,
    type: "dateTime",
    renderHeader: () => (
      <FormattedMessage id={"history.param.deviceStatusDate"} />
    )
  }
];

<div style={{ height: "90%", width: "100%" }}>
  <XGrid
    pageSize={50}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pagination={true}
  />
</div>;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, MUI docs page is using `useDemoData`and does not explain anything in regard. Very insightful though (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: Where you able to add those checkbox filter options?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add these 2 key values in your column object:

```
type: "singleSelect",
valueOptions: ["select1","select2",.....]
```

change it from

```
{
field: 'brand',
headerName: 'Brand',
width: 150,
editable: false,
}
```

to

```
{
field: 'brand',
headerName: 'Brand',
width: 150,
editable: false,
type: "singleSelect",
valueOptions: ["select1","select2",.....]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Anhad! Your answer seems to include code, could you please format it correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: thanks @MikeSzyndel for the suggestion, done the changes!

Comment: @Anhad but this will just let you select one option at a time, the original question was like checkbox with multiple filter selection

Answer (score 1):

You can add `type:"singleSelect"` to your columns array followed by `valueOptions` to give the array of values to be displayed in the dropdown. I have added an example below for reference

```js
const columns = [

  {
    field: "Status",
    flex: 1,
    type:"singleSelect",
    valueOptions:[{value:"item1",label:"item1"},{value:"item2",label:"item2"},{value:"item3",label:"item3"}],/>
  }
];
```